# Is 2h 5m enough time for a layover in Toronto for a SCL-YYZ-LHR flight?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, layovers, short-connections, yyz

I'm eyeing an itinerary on Air Canada which would take me from Santiago to London Heathrow via Toronto (YYZ) which would allow 2 hours and 5 minutes in between the two flights. Is that enough? When I complete

- Arriving from: International
- Arriving on airline: Air Canada
- Departing to: International
- Departing on airline: Air Canada

on the form at http://www.torontopearson.com/Connecting.aspx it returns a connecting guide which suggests I won't have to pick up my luggage—is that really the case?. By the way, I am a Chilean citizen, and understand I need a Canadian transit visa.

Comment: See also here https://www.aircanada.com/ca/en/aco/home/fly/at-the-airport/airport-information/toronto-pearson-international-airport/int-int.html. No need to pick up your bags.According to https://www.aircanada.com/ca/en/aco/home/plan/check-in-information/minimum-connection-times.html minimum connection time is 60 minutes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your best source of information on this is the airline, who wouldn't sell you the ticket if they thought you couldn't make the connection. But some extra information to reassure you:

- you do not have to change terminals
- you may not have to go through customs at all - for some flights you can stay airside and go through a much simpler process
- you may or may not have to re-clear security, but the longest security line I have ever waited in at YYZ was 30 minutes
- your bags will be checked through so you don't need to wait to get those

If you stay airside with no need to clear customs or security, and your first flight is on time, you will probably spend 90 minutes sitting at the gate wondering if you should go shopping in the terminal. And even if you need 30 min for security, 30 min for customs (both estimates are probably double or triple what you really need) and your flight is 30 min late, you'll still make it.

(I've never changed planes in YYZ. But I have landed there from international flights, and left from there for international flights, many many times.)